# how to change insert fields in auth - laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using this migration :

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('fname');
        $table->string('lname');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I installed `auth`. in the `register` url when I want to create an user I got this message :

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values..
```

I know what says the error, but I don't want to change `fname` to `name`.

Comment: You'll have to modify the registration controller to save the right data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the

```
app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController(Laravel 5.3)
app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController(Laravel 5, Laravel 5.1, Laravel 5.2)
```

you will find something like below.

```
  protected function create(array $data)
  {
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
  }
```

you can change name key of above array as fname.

Answer (score -1):

Go to app/User.php class and add these field to the $fillable array.

Comment: Not the issue. It appears when creating a user he's filling in a non-existent `$user->name` value.